# How to retrieve a unique character from a string using while loop

Tags: python

I was tasked with creating a function that looks for the unique char in a string and from there add the value of that to 10. For this specific scenario dice_str will always have a len of 3, and there will always be a unique char within that str. This is my code so far:

```
def get_point_score(dice_str):
    unique = ""
    i = 0
    
    while len(unique) != 1:
        if dice_str[i] not in dice_str[i+1:]:
            unique += dice_str[i]
            sum = 10 + int(unique)
        else:
            i += 1
            unique += unique
        
        
    return sum
```

Expected output:

```
dice_str = "141"
value = 14

Got:
value = 11
```

We were asked to solve this using while loops, indexing and find().

I was thinking of iterating through every element in the string and using indexing to see if it is repeated, and if it is repeated to increment i by 1 and continue checking until this is no longer the case. From the output it looks like I have failed to implement this properly, so then I was thinking of using find() and once find() returns -1, add the element to the empty string, but I also am not sure how to implement that properly. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It outputs the correct value for me.

Comment: I thought so too. It works for "141," but It is not correct generally.

Comment: I don't get this statement, "add the value of that to 10" -> add 10 to each unique value or at the end?

Comment: @HenryEcker Ah you are correct. There are some corner cases like if there are no unique element or what if unique element is the last one?

Comment: Also, I see every time `sum` is getting overridden by a new value, is that the expected?

Comment: @MaranSowthri dice_str will always have a unique value in it, so 10 will be added to the unique value and stored in sum

Comment: @Goion Yes I was also confused as to how I can account for if the unique value was at the end, how then would I check if it is repeated in the first two elements, more if statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your check `if dice_str[i] not in dice_str[i + 1:]:`.

Take note of this example `"116"`

On your first time through you will check if `1` is in `16`. Which it is.

Then you check if `1` is in `6` which it is not. But then you perform this operation:

`unique += dice_str[i]`

However in this case, your unique value is `6` (index `i + 1`) not `1` (index `i`).

---

You were really close in your implementation. Instead of testing if a value is `not in` the next slice up, you can build a list that excludes the current index, and test against that instead:

```py
def get_point_score(dice_str):
    i = 0
    unique = None
    while not unique:
        if dice_str[i] not in (dice_str[:i] + dice_str[i + 1:]):
            unique = dice_str[i]
        i += 1
    return 10 + int(unique)
```

*Warning this will raise an error if your list does not contain at least one unique value.

---

Given that you're guaranteed a length 3 string with a single unique character, you can just do left/right comparison.

```py
def get_point_score(dice_str):
    left_match = dice_str[0] == dice_str[1]  # Do 0 and 1 Match?
    right_match = dice_str[1] == dice_str[2]  # Do 1 and 2 Match?

    if not left_match and not right_match:
        # Neither Match (Middle Unique)
        unique = dice_str[1]
    elif left_match:
        # 0 and 1 Match, but 1 and 2 don't (Right Unique)
        unique = dice_str[2]
    else:
        # 0 and 1 Don't Match, but 1 and 2 do (Left Unique)
        unique = dice_str[0]
    return 10 + int(unique)


print(get_point_score("116"))
print(get_point_score("141"))
print(get_point_score("722"))
```

Output:

```
16
14
17
```